# Is axis framework compatible with java version 1.1

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have to use axis framework to write a web service client. But some of the computers that will use this client, has java version 1.1.8. Is it possible to use axis on these machines without upgrading java versions?

Comment: Download Java 1.1 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html and make your own tests.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. The minimum JDK from the [documentation](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis/1_0/dependencies.html) for axis version 1.0,

> ```
> Product   Version     URL
> JDK       1.3.1_04    http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/
> ```